# Can memcache be scaled horizontally?

Tags: php, session, memcached, scalability

**Current scenario:**

Web app files is stored in geographically separated data centers (Server A, Server B).

Database server is also geographically separated and is used as session handler (Server C).

I am planning to replace the database server and use PHP memcache as session handler.

**Questions:**

1. Can memcache scale vertically? (e.g., session handler will now be Server C, D, E)
2. Can the app servers (Server A and B) "round robin" to Server C, D, E? E.g., if Server C is down, session handler will failover to Server D or E?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean memcached if that's the case then Yes,
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Scaling.Memcached.html

Comment: Yes but specifically referring to PHP memcache

Comment: Yes it can be scaled horizontally.